# Where is the data return from a failed ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl, iis-7, error-handling

I am unable to get the returned output from a failed ajax request.

It returns the following.

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n";
print "Status: 400 Bad Request\n\n";
print $template->output;
```

But I cannot find the returned data anywhere in the ajax response

```
error: function(jqXHR){
        showDialog(jqXHR.responseText,'AJAX Failed');
    }
```

All that does is show me `Bad Request`?

How do I get access to the actual returned `HTML` output from the 400 response?

Success works fine.

```
success: function(data){
        showDialog(data,'AJAX Success');
    }
```

So where is the data stored in an 'error' return?

**UPDATE:**
I've given up as I don't seem to be getting any returned data if error code not a 2xx , so I've refactored my success to deal with 207 status code

```
success: function(data,status,jqXHR){  
        if(jqXHR.status === 207)
        {                         
            showDialog(data);
        }
        if(jqXHR.status === 200)
        {                         
            uploadComplete();
        }                                              
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, the body of the error response _should_ be in `jqXHR.responseText`, although there's an argument that `4xx` errors shouldn't have bodies.

Comment: What is contained in the responseText?  Anything at all?

Comment: I suggest you try with Chrome and look at the "Network" tab of the developer tools - it'll reveal whether your web server is actually passing on the content or not for the `4xx` error.

Comment: What is your server technology/language ?

Comment: In addition, you didn't post in the question your data representation code.

Comment: 1. jqXHR.responseText = All that does is show me Bad Request?<br>

2. Server = IIS7<br>

3. Language = Perl<br>

4. data representation code = Don't understand this question, can you reword please.

I have also tried using 500 codes, but no joy... I'll look at FF console see if I can see any output

Comment: I don't seem to be getting any data returned, so how do I fail an ajax request and output user defined error messages from my application?

Comment: @1DMF Welcome to SO from TT

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned IIS7, it would be a good attempt to configure it that it will ***not*** use its built-in messages for error responses, but will use yours.

Change the **`ExistingResponse`** attribute to **`PassThrough`** at the IIS configuration.

From [IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors):

> PassThrough - Leaves the response untouched if an existing response
>   exists.

You'll find this attribute under the `<httpErrors>` section which you can configure at the server level in the ApplicationHost.config file and at the site and application level in the appropriate Web.config file.

After that change, **recheck** the `jqXHR.responseText` property content.

Comment: Sounds interesting, Though this would be for the entire site, so unless I refactor all responses for all apps running on this particular domain, I think this might cause problems. But it is certainly food for thought. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for statusText? This is what I use:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Foo.ashx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d) {
                    console.log(msg.d);
                } else {
                    //Nada
                }
            },

            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: [quote]
Looking for statusText?
[/quote]

No, I wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I did some refactoring of my backend code and have it working....

Serverside (just an extract for demonstration purposes)

```
$error_txt[2] = "<p>You are no longer logged in.</p><p>This may be because you have been idle for 1 hour and have been logged out of the system.</p><p>If this is not the case please contact <a href=mailto:support\@mydomain.com> support\@mydomain.com</a> to resolve the problem.</p>";

print "Content-type: text/html\n";
print "Status: 400 $error_txt[2]\n\n";
```

Clientside AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(frm).attr('action'),  // server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {  // custom xhr for progress meter
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',showProgress, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
        return myXhr;
    },
    data: myData, 
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data,status,jqXHR){  
        if(jqXHR.status === 200)
        {                         
            uploadComplete();
        }                                              
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
        showDialog(errorThrown,'AJAX Failed');
    }

});
```

I am now getting a JQuery dialog displaying the error message for 4xx codes :-)